# How to set TableLayoutPanel cell's size

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a `TableLayoutPanel` with `PictureBox` + `Label` in each cell. I have got it all right but I just can't set the cells sizes to be the same! I'm trying to have 4 columns with endless number of rows, and I would like the cell to be in the `Label` width, unless the `Label` width is smaller than the `Picture` width.

For now, my code pretty much works, it just doesn't set the cell size because I have no idea how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim movieN As Integer = MoviesDataSet.movies.Rows.Count
    Dim tablePanel As New TableLayoutPanel

    With tablePanel
        .Size = New Point(650, 450)
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows
        .AutoScroll = True
        .Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(5, 50)
        .CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Inset
    End With


    For Each MovieRow As DataRow In MoviesDataSet.Tables("movies").Rows
        'define two new controls to be added
        Dim myLabel As New Label
        Dim myPicture As New PictureBox
        Dim container As New Panel

        'set the properties of the new controls
        myLabel.Text = MovieRow("movieName")
        myLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(30, 110)
        With myPicture
            .Image = Image.FromFile(MovieRow("moviePhoto"))
            .Tag = MovieRow("ID")
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(2, 2)
        End With

        'here we add the controls to a flow layout panel to
        'manage the positioning of the controls but you could
        'explicitly set the location of the controls if you 
        'just wanted to add them to the forms controls collection
        With container
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
            .Controls.Add(myPicture)
            .Controls.Add(myLabel)
        End With


        With tablePanel.Controls
            .Add(container)
        End With

        'here we add a handler for the picture boxs click event
        AddHandler myPicture.Click, AddressOf MyPictureClickEvent
        AddHandler myPicture.MouseHover, AddressOf MyPictureHoverEvent
    Next
    Me.Controls.Add(tablePanel)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cell width to be the same as the wider of the `PictureBox` or `Label`, and you're placing them both in the same cell by wrapping them in a `Panel` then set the `Panel`'s [AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.autosizemode.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) property to `AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink`, and its [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.autosize.aspx) property to `True`.  If you then do the same thing for the `TableLayoutPanel` it will make each cell grow or shrink depending on the size of the `Panel` and the `Panel` will do the same depending on the size of the controls inside it.